# Using Microsoft Print To PDF in VB.NET resulting in 0 KB "PDF"

Tags: vb.net, pdf

I am experiencing some problems when trying to print to pdf.
Maybe, some of you cracks could have a look to my code snippet ?

```
[...]

Private tmpPDFName As String
Private printPDF As Printing.PrintDocument

''' <summary>
''' Delegate Method "finishPrintingPDF" should be called when finishing Printing 
''' </summary>
''' <param name="sender"></param>
''' <param name="e"></param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Sub finishPrintingPDF(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs)

    Dim targetDir As String

    Try
        targetDir = "C:\Finished\"
        If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetDir) Then System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetDir)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    End Try

    System.IO.File.Copy(tmpPDFName, targetDir & "123.pdf")
    Application.DoEvents()
    System.IO.File.Delete(tmpPDFName)

End Sub


''' <summary>
''' Using "Microsoft Print To PDF" Printer to print to PDF
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Overloads Sub PrintDocumentToPDF()

    Dim tempUserDir As String : tempUserDir = String.Empty
    tempUserDir = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.CurrentUserApplicationData & "\Temp"

    If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(tempUserDir) Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(tempUserDir)
    End If

    tmpPDFName = tempUserDir & "\123.pdf"

    If System.IO.File.Exists(tmpPDFName) Then System.IO.File.Delete(tmpPDFName)

    printPDF = New Printing.PrintDocument
    printPDF.DocumentName = "Test"
    printPDF.PrintController = New Printing.StandardPrintController()
    ' CLSDomePrinting performing the printing (no error there, so I ignore this class)
    AddHandler printPDF.PrintPage, AddressOf CLSDoSomePrinting
    ' When finished Printing, the temporary file shall be copied to its final place 
    ' The only problem is: There is no really guarentee, it works
    ' Sometimes PDF is created as expected, but sometimes PDF has a size of 0 Bytes and is empty...
    ' Is there a proofed way to print to pdf using "Microsoft Print to PDF" ?
    AddHandler printPDF.EndPrint, AddressOf finishPrintingPDF

    Dim prnSettings As New Printing.PrinterSettings
    With prnSettings
        .Copies = 1
        .PrinterName = "Microsoft Print To PDF"
        .PrintFileName = tmpPDFName
        .PrintToFile = True
    End With

    printPDF.PrinterSettings = prnSettings
    ' So far, so good
    printPDF.Print()

End Sub
```

So, this would be my approach. I dont see a reason, why my code snippet should not work. Most, it results in a file with 0 Bytes.

I am working on virtual machine (Hyper V) in Windows 10 enviroment.

Thank you, in advance
Stephan

Comment: I suspect your problem is that at the point that the copy command is executed, the print queue job is still processing the conversion to a PDF.  As a test, remove the file delete statement and check your _temp_ folder using Windows Explorer to see if that hold a complete file.  You could also open the "Microsoft Print To PDF" queue to watch the progress.

Comment: Okay, I understand your point. Is there another option than handling the event EndPrint to identify when a file has been created ? Then copy the successfully created temporary file to its target path ? Maybe over an asynchronous way ?

Comment: I have little experience with this, but you could try using [LocalPrintServer Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.localprintserver?view=netframework-4.7.2) to obtain the "Microsoft Print To PDF" queue.  Then set up a polling loop on the queue checking the [PrintQueue.NumberOfJobs Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printqueue.numberofjobs?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Printing_PrintQueue_NumberOfJobs) or some other property to determine if the job is done. Just remember to  call the PrintQueue.Refresh Method as part of the loop.

Comment: I found another approach over the FileSystemWatcher class. For details see
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.waitforchangedresult?view=netframework-4.7.2